# Adding custom fields to general product page in admin in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to add the custom fields to woocommerce general product tab. I know this can be achieved adding code to theme's function.php, but I need to add the fields without using function.php, So that my plugin is seperately installable

Comment: I'm no expert but how about creating a plugin and use Woo Commerce hooks?

Comment: Also wouldn't product attributes be enough for you?